# what is the default directory where dask workers store results or files.?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

```
[mapr@impetus-i0057 latest_code_deepak]$ dask-worker 172.26.32.37:8786
distributed.nanny - INFO -         Start Nanny at: 'tcp://172.26.32.36:50930'
distributed.diskutils - WARNING - Found stale lock file and directory '/home/mapr/latest_code_deepak/dask-worker-space/worker-PwEseH', purging
distributed.worker - INFO -       Start worker at:   tcp://172.26.32.36:41694
distributed.worker - INFO -          Listening to:   tcp://172.26.32.36:41694
distributed.worker - INFO -              bokeh at:          172.26.32.36:8789
distributed.worker - INFO -              nanny at:         172.26.32.36:50930
distributed.worker - INFO - Waiting to connect to:    tcp://172.26.32.37:8786
distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------
distributed.worker - INFO -               Threads:                          8
distributed.worker - INFO -                Memory:                   33.52 GB
distributed.worker - INFO -       Local Directory: /home/mapr/latest_code_deepak/dask-worker-spa                                                                 ce/worker-AkBPtM
distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------
distributed.worker - INFO -         Registered to:    tcp://172.26.32.37:8786
distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------
```

what is the default directory where a dask-worker maintains the temporary files, such as task results, or the downloaded files which was uploaded using upload_file() method from the client.?

for example:-

```
def my_task_running_on_dask_worker():
    //fetch the file from hdfs
    // process the file
    //store the file back into hdfs
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default a dask worker places a directory in `./dask-worker-space/worker-#######` where `######` is some random string for that particular worker.

You can change this location using the `--local-directory` keyword to the `dask-worker` executable.

The warning that you're seeing in this line

```
distributed.diskutils - WARNING - Found stale lock file and directory '/home/mapr/latest_code_deepak/dask-worker-space/worker-PwEseH', purging
```

says that a Dask worker noticed that the directory for *another* worker wasn't cleaned up, presumably because it failed in some hard way.  This worker is cleaning up the space left behind from the previous worker.

#### Edit

You can see which worker creates which directory either by looking at the logs of each worker (They print out their local directory)

```
$ dask-worker localhost:8786
distributed.worker - INFO -       Start worker at:      tcp://127.0.0.1:36607
...
distributed.worker - INFO -       Local Directory: /home/mrocklin/dask-worker-space/worker-ks3mljzt
```

Or programatically by calling `client.scheduler_info()`

```
>>> client.scheduler_info()
{'address': 'tcp://127.0.0.1:34027',
 'id': 'Scheduler-bd88dfdf-e3f7-4b39-8814-beae779248f1',
 'services': {'bokeh': 8787},
 'type': 'Scheduler',
 'workers': {'tcp://127.0.0.1:33143': {'cpu': 7.7,
    ... 
   'local_directory': '/home/mrocklin/dask-worker-space/worker-8kvk_l81',
  },
...
```

Comment: Thanks..if we start multiple dask-workers from the same directory, then under the ./dask-worker-space, I can see multiple worker-##### folders. so I wanted to know which worker-#### folder belongs to which worker process.? do we any way to know this.?

Comment: You are awesome.. made my day..!!

Answer (score 0):

When running a client using `distributed=2022.10.2', I see that the default path is:

- `/var/folders/v6/.../dask-worker-space/worker-...`  on Mac M1;
- `/tmp/dask-worker-space/worker-...` on Ubuntu.